# Getting error while building signature apk and bundle Invalid keystore format

Tags: java, android-studio, gradle, keystore, jks

**Execution failed for task ':app:signReleaseBundle'.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
> Failed to read key key0 from store "F:\extra\pf\app bundle\mathkey.jks": Invalid keystore format**

**my gradle file **

````
android {
    compileSdkVersion 32
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "***.***.***"
        minSdkVersion 26
        targetSdkVersion 32
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true

            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    repositories {
        maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
    implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:10.2.3'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:10.2.3'


    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:19.3.0'


    //-------- firebse
    // Recommended: Add the Firebase SDK for Google Analytics.
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:21.1.0'
    // Add the Firebase Crashlytics SDK.
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics:18.2.12'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'  
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics' ```



i have done every thing but didn't get any solution
````

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: where ever i try to build signature apk or bundle it give me this error 

`A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade Failed to read key key0 from store "F:\extra\pf\app bundle\mathkey.jks": Invalid keystore format** `

Comment: I solved the problem by deleting the folder of JDK 1.8